# stored property "text" without initial value prevents synthesized initializers

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm learning swift and have came up with the simple code below.

```
class ARandom{
    var number: Int = 0
    var text: String
}
```

However, Xcode displays the following Error:

```
stored property "text" without initial value prevents synthesized initializers
```

Why is this happening? what is an synthesized initialiser? why "text" without initial value prevents systhesised initialiser? Could someone please kindly explain it to me? THanks in advance for any help!

Comment: FWIW you'd also get this error if you've wrote like `let foo: String!`. The compiler knows that `foo` is a `let` and can never mutate, hence it throws an error. The fix is to change `let` to `var`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have a few options here.

1. Make `text` optional.

   `var text: String?`
2. Give `text` a default value

   `var text: String = ""`
3. Give `text` a value in `ARandom`'s initializer

   `init() { text = "" }`

The reason this happens is your are defining `text` as a `String`.  It is not optional. Essentially you are saying that it always is a `String` and never `nil`.

With your current code if you created a new instance of `ARandom`, `text` would have no value - and that is not possible if `text` is not optional

Apple's docs probably explain it a bit better

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an
>   appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or
>   structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an
>   indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an
>   initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the
>   property’s definition.

Comment: In addition, if your use pattern is to create the object once and never modify it then make it a `struct` and have all member variables defined with `let`. This will create a synthesized init which takes values for all unset variables.

Comment: thank you so much! that is a very detailed explanation! solved a lot of my misunderstanding! thanks again!

Comment: @KennethBruno thanks for the heads up! really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help. Using invariants (an object that can't be modified) is a good idea. It simplifies programming in many ways. Take a look at this discussion: [Why are invariants important in Computer Science](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/165816/212886)

Comment: Anyone seeing this, double check that `var` was used to define your optional. Doing `let text: String?` will cause the same error.